# What are the coefficients in the expansion of the (integer) power of a sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

> What are the coefficients in the expansion of
>   $$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^k ,$$
>   assuming the $a_i$'s are commuting, and $k,n\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

E.g.
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 + 2\sum_{i<j} a_i a_j $$

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^3 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^3 + 3{n\choose 2}\sum_{i\neq j} a_i a_j^2 + 6{n\choose 3}\sum_{i\neq j\neq k} a_i a_j a_k$$

Is there a general formula ?

Comment: There is a multinomial theorem at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

By multinomial

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^k =\sum_{k_1+\dots +k_n=k}{n\choose k_1\dots k_n}a_1^{k_1}\cdots a_n^{k_n} $$

where $${n\choose k_1\dots k_n}=\frac{n!}{k_1!\dots k_n!}$$